# Erro ao usar a função split e remover certos caracteres de um arquivo java

Tags: java, arquivo

A ideia é separar pedaços com a função split que não contenha espaços, virgula, ponto e virgula, etc.
Mas a função não separa corretamente, separando a maioria das vezes somente o espaço.

```
public String[] getTokens(String s)
{
    String[] tokens;
    tokens = s.split(",");
    tokens = s.split(" ");
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        if(tokens[i].equals(";") || tokens[i].equals(","))
        {
            tokens[i] =" ";
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

public void execute()
{
    File[] filesArray = dt.returnFiles();
    for(File f : filesArray)
    {
        try
        {
            fileContent = dt.loadFile(f);

            for(int i=0; i < fileContent.size(); i++)
            {

                if(fileContent.get(i).equals(",") || fileContent.get(i).equals(";") || 
                        fileContent.get(i).isEmpty())
                {
                    fileContent.remove(i);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Foi feita a alteração!

Comment: Alan, a imagem você pode deixar na pergunta, o problema maior era nao ter o código em texto, como tem agora.

Comment: Boto fé, eu achei que era errado...

Comment: O problema do teu código é que você está sobrescrevendo a variável tokens após o segundo split. Tente passar todos os caracteres que você gostaria de usar como parâmetro da função split, mais ou menos assim: `tokens = s.split("[\\s;,]");`
Com isso, você conseguirá dividir a string por todos os caracteres.

Comment: Olha mano, tenho o seguinte trecho como exemplo que não está dando certo:

`; Programa LOGICA.ASM

; Este programa testa todas as operacoes logicas da ALU

; Cada teste incrementa o registrador r4 se for bem sucedido.
; no final, se todos os testes forem bem sucedidos, a pontuacao
; atinge valor 10, que eh armazenada em Mem[1000]
; Cada teste verifica se a tabela verdade para a operacao
; esta sendo gerada corretamente.

zeros r4

teste0:
 zeros r0  ; Operacao C = A & B;
 zeros r1
 and r1,r0,r1
 jf.zero teste1
`
Sabe o porque o split não está funcionando?

Comment: Alan, você fez duas atribuições para a variável `s` seguidas. Imagine que você escreveu numa página de um caderno o resultado da operação `s.split(",")`, daí você arrancou a página fora e agora (com `s` intacto) `s.split(" ")`. Vale sempre lembrar que em Java strings são imutáveis